# Smallest Prime number

Tags: primes

I am trying to do a program to find the least prime number to be computed such that the prime number divided by 4 different distinct natural numbers leaves a reminder which is the smallest of the 4 natural numbers.

Example 1

Input :  3 4 5 1

The smallest input number is 1. So we are looking for the smallest prime P such that P MOD 1 = 1, P MOD 3 = 1, P MOD 4 = 1 and P MOD 5 = 1.

Output : 61

Explanation : 1 is the smallest natural number. The smallest prime number formed by dividing it by 3,4,5,1 results in 61.

Example 2

Input :  3 4 5 2

Output : None

Explanation : Any number divided by 4 leaving reminder 2 has to be an even number

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: To find the least prime number which satisfies the above condition

Comment: This isn't a code writing service.  Please [edit] your question with your attempt so far and what your specific problem is.

Comment: Even with your example I don't understand the question.