# How to solve the problem to find least prime number from 1 to 100 and if there is better than this code please kindly update it

Tags: java, arrays, primes, nosuchelementexception

I was trying to get **Smallest Prime Number(p)** by dividing it with set of **Distinct (n) Natural Numbers** where **(q)** is the **Least Natural Number** and the **Remainder** should be **q**.

> Constraints are 1<n<100 and p<100.

```
Example 1:
```

`input (n): 3 4 5 1`

`output (p): 61`

Explanation:

Here n+1 numbers are 3,4,5 and 1 where q = 1(is the least natural number).

The smallest number is 1 which leaves remainder 1 when divided by 3, 4 and  5 is 61 and is Prime. Hence output is `61`.

```
Example 2:
```

`input (n): 3 4 5 2`

`output (p): None`

Explanation:

Here q=2. Any number that when divided by 4 leaves remainder 2 must be an even number  e.g. 6,10,14 etc.

Hence it can't be prime .

Hence the output is `None`

`Here is my code:`

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main{
  public static void main(String [] args){
    int[] n = {3,4,5};
    int q =1,i,temp1 = 0,p;
    String temp =new String("None");
        for(p=3;p<100;p++){
           if(p%n[0] == q && p%n[1] == q && p%n[2] == q)
                  temp1 = p;
        }
     if(temp1%n[0] == q && temp1%n[1] == q && temp1%n[2] == q)
        System.out.println(temp1);
     else
        System.out.println(temp);
    }
}
```

`Input : 3,4,5,1`
`Output is 61.`

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: What happens when you run your code? What do you want it to do instead? Please [edit] your question with additional details. See [ask] for tips on getting the help you want.

Comment: @WJS  yes the question is to find least prime number from the range of 0 to 100 which divides the distinct natural number i.e 3,4 and 5 except 1, but the remainder is 1 which is least natural number. and I am getting run time error...

Comment: What is your runtime error?  I'm guessing an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: @Ryan ok then how to solve it??

Comment: Without you telling us what your error is we don't know what to look at.  You're also not telling us your inputs.  I'm trying to make sense of your code, but you have unused variables and can't tell what you're trying to do.

Comment: Your problem statement is very unclear.  Perhaps you should provide a specific example of inputs and desired output?

Comment: Hi @Ryan I am getting runtime error called **java.util.NoSuchElementException at n[i] = scan.nextInt();**

Comment: Seems like this question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71618001/238704) are an attempt to ask the same question. I still don't understand what is being asked, even looking at both questions.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk yes both the questions are same. The point is to find the Prime number which is divisible by 3,4 and 5 and getting remainder 1.

Comment: So you have a set S of distinct natural numbers. Let q be the minimum of S, and let T = S - {q}. Find the smallest prime p for which p = q mod t for each t in T. Is that the problem?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk of course and I have updated my code but still it is shabby and i am newbie so i need help to improve this code...

Answer (score 1):

Your code is sort of lumped together.  It would facilitate the process and make it easier to debug if you broke it up into methods.  But don't be prompting for input during the test phase.  Hardcode an array of `ints` with which to test.

I suggest writing two methods.

- the first method ( e.g. `isPrime`) is to determine if a value is a prime.  There are many good answers on this site on how to compute primes.  Just do a search.
- then initialize the smallest prime to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (which is also a prime)
- the second method simply calls the first with a candidate and does the following:

  - if the `isPrime` method returns true,

    - compare it to the smallest prime.
    - if smaller, assign to smallest prime, else ignore.
  - if the `isPrime` method returns false, ignore.
- when you're done, you will have the smallest prime

By breaking the code into methods you can focus on one thing at a time.  The `isPrime` method will be the more complicated of the two. Make certain you use print statements to help in the debug process.

here are some things to consider.

- to check if `N` is a prime, only check remainders of divisors from `2` to the `sqrt(N)`.
- you can first try `2` and then continue with `3` thru `sqrt(N)` incrementing by `2`.

You may want to check out the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) as alternative to finding primes.